# write client side api that uses libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, rest, client

I've written the server side of an api, that serves html via json using REST via codeigniter.
I'm investigating how to write a client side api with javascript, to get the data from the server via the api, present it in the dom and bind events to it.

One of the things I need at the client side is jquery. Now I'm wondering what happens if the client already is using another version of jquery, that conflicts the version I need?

Comment: Try to use iFrame at the client side

Comment: Yes, that would work, but iFrames have their disadvantages. Is there a solution without using an iFrame?

Comment: Make a requirement list for your API or Just go with every possible conflict and fix it, or use native JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use multiple versions of jquery simultaneously by assigning jQuery.noConflict() to a variable right after the jquery version is loaded. Then just use that variable as your reference to the version you need.